# Redireccionar de index.jsp a otro jsp según botón presionado

Tags: java, web, jsp, maven

Estuve viendo mil temas acá y en la versión en inglés y no puedo solucionarlo
Quiero saber si se puede hacer esto:

Yo tengo 3 botones en mi index.jsp (no necesariamente juntos) y quiero que, según el que yo presione, me redirija a un jsp diferente que se encuentra en WEB-INF/views.

Lo que quiero hacer es que los 3 botones me dirijan a un mismo servlet y este servlet identifique qué botón fue presionado para redireccionar al jsp que corresponde.

Yo intenté esto:
En el index.jsp (Uso Bootstrap):

```
            <button type="submit" id="boton1"  class="btn btn-primary" onclick="function goForward() {
                                <%  request.setAttribute("nextPage", new String("jsp1"));%>
        }" >JSP 1</button>
```

En el servlet:

```
        try {

        String nextPage = (String) request.getAttribute("nextPage");


        RequestDispatcher dispatcher;
        String dir = "/WEB-INF/views/"+ nextPage + ".jsp";
        dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( dir );
        dispatcher.forward( request, response );

    } catch (IOException e) {               
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }
```

Pero al apretar el botón no encuentra el jsp: 
/mavenproject1/WEB-INF/views/null.jsp
De alguna manera, el servlet recibe siempre "null" como valor de "nextPage".

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: Revisa la petición que estas mandando al servidor si realmente la esta mandando otra opción es mandes la petición por ajax así te aseguras que el parámetro llega correctamente.

Comment: @solamente me podrías ayudar para mandar la petición por ajax?

Comment: Googlea e intentalo y en caso de error te ayudare

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes un botón de tipo submit asumo que tienes un form.

Para mi lo mejor que puedes hacer es crear un parámetro "hidden" en el formulario y leerlo una vez que la petición llegue al servlet.

```
<form action="/miservlet">

<input type="hidden" id="nextPage" name="nextPage" value=""/>

<!-- En la funcion onlick del boton estableces el valor del parametro-->

<button type="submit" id="boton1"  class="btn btn-primary" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('nextpage').value = 'jsp1';" >JSP 1</button>

</form>
```

En tu servlet puedes leer el parámetro así:

```
String nextPage = (String) request.getParameter("nextPage");
```

Comment: Error HTTP 404
/MediaManager/WEB-INF/views/.jsp. Retornó una cadena vacía, al parecer no llegó a completar el "value" con la function goForward

Comment: prueba a quitar la función y poner directamente `onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('nextpage').value = 'jsp1';"` He editado la respuesta

Comment: Tampoco. Lo que está pasando es que se envía el formulario antes de que el valor "value" sea modificado. Es lo mismo que me pasaba con mi código. En este caso se retorna una cadena vacía. En mi caso retornaba null porque le mandaba un objeto

Comment: Otra cosa que puedes hacer es crear un formulario para cada botón e inicializar el valor del parámetro hidden directamente. Tendrías un <form> para cada botón.

Comment: Acabo de hacer justamente eso y funciona. Creo que es la mejor solución de momento. Si se me ocurre algo mejor editaré el post. Muchas gracias.